# Error reading data from geomesa(bigtable)

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I'm having a problem to read data from Geomesa(BigTable).
I can connect to the source of data, but when I try to get the data returns the following error:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pleaes use addRange(byte[], byte[]) instead. Pleaes use addRange(byte[], byte[]) instead.`

What could be the cause? Anyone already have this error before?

I tried to change the geoserver dependencies for the ones on the geomesa documentation and tried to use the updated version of almost all jar files.

Comment: For future folks, this is being tracked with this JIRA issue: https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-2898.

Comment: I managed to run geomesa in version 2.4.1 and geoserver 2.15.5. There seems to be some compatibility issue with geomesa 3.0.0 and geoserver 2.17.2.
At least that's my guess.

Comment: Interesting.  The error seems to be coming from the Bigtable library code here: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/pull/1203/files/16ac46810c8b30faccc61ba20b346f2c8f0e4473

I'm guessing there's a version mismatch or other issue.  That said, if you found a working version, that's great to hear!